# Instantiating UserManager and Loading Foreign Key'd Objects from IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've got a basic question about how to stand-up a new instance of UserManager (or access it where I need it in the request stack), and then how to use it to get an IdentityUser instance that includes custom foreign key objects (i.e., in the case that IdentityUser has been extended as a custom ApplicationUser). For example, I have:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base(){ }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; } = new Person();
}
```

Person being a POCO entity that houses a few items that I'd rather not put directly into the IdentityUser type.

And in my web project `Startup.cs`, I've registered a custom claims transformation, like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformation>();
```

And in my ClaimsTransformation class, I'm doing a transform operation like this:

```
public class ClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (
            principal != null
            & (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == CustomClaimType.DisplayName)
            && (principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email) || principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)))
        )
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

            if (identity != null && identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                CoreUserService userService = new CoreUserService();
                ApplicationUser applicationUser = await userService.FetchAsync(identity);

                if (applicationUser != null)
                {
                    Claim claimDisplayName = CustomClaim.Create(CustomClaimType.DisplayName, applicationUser.Person.Name.DisplayName);

                    if (claimDisplayName != null)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(claimDisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

And this does work. You can't see everything that's happening under the hood, there, but the bottom line is that I'm going and getting the related Person entity by addressing my DAL DbContext, directly. And that seems unhygienic. I'd certainly prefer to have UserManager do this. I don't like mixing and matching modes of working. If I'm going to use AspIdentity then that's what I want to stick with for all identity management.

What I'm not really sure of is where in the request stack my TransformAsync method gets called, and whether I can have a UserManager passed into it, or else-wise available to it. I tried firing one up in the context of the method, but -- my goodness -- there's a truckload of overhead to it! I'm not going to stand-up such a costly object if I don't absolutely have to.

But even if I have a handle to a UserManager, I honestly don't know how to have it return an ApplicationUser to me that includes my related Person object. I don't know why I can't figure this one out, either. Seems like it should be pretty simple, and it's not.

Comment: Have you tried injecting the `UserManager` into the constructor of `ClaimsTransformation`?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that shows how TransformAsync is called, much less where it gets injected.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch It's right there: `services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformation>();`...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's only the declaration.

Comment: So, to answer both the above comments. I'd love to be able to inject it into the ClaimsTransformation constructor. That would be the cleanest method. But to address the second question, I actually don't know where the thing is getting called. It's some sort of magic, I presume, related to the way the class is registered in startup.cs. I imagine it gets called somewhere in the request stack, by Http handler objects that are part of .net core hosting.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yeah, and the documentation states that it's used by the `IAuthenticationService`: "`TransformAsync`: Provides a central transformation point to change the specified principal. Note: this will be run on each AuthenticateAsync call, so its safer to return a new ClaimsPrincipal if your transformation is not idempotent."

Comment: It's used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationservice.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationService__ctor_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_IAuthenticationSchemeProvider_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_IAuthenticationHandlerProvider_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_IClaimsTransformation_)

Comment: Yes, exactly. It gets called when the user is authenticated, and from anything I can see, I don't know that I can give it visibility to the UserManager that's doing the authenticating. It's weird. There's gotta be a way to do that.

Comment: That's why I asked you to try, you should be able to inject it since a request is alive at that point

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thing is, none of *my* code calls it. That happens somewhere automagically, as a result of the class being registered at startup. I can't isolate where it's being called.

Comment: @MichaelDoleman - typically you would give the configuration a scoped lifetime

Comment: I get it that you don't know how Dependency Injection works then? Please take the time to read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) so you can understand what I mean

Comment: @MichaelDoleman - The dependency injection framework is creating your object because something else, in this case the identity framework has a dependency it needs satisfying for that interface.  So, because you configured it, it creates it and calls it.  Likewise, if you create a dependency of an IApplicationUser, it will create the configured IApplicationUser object

Comment: No, I get how dependency injection works. I've got the dependency on UserManager and SignInManager already set-up in my Startup.cs Configure method by adding app.UseAuthentication(). That gives me instances of UserManager available everywhere except -- seemingly -- inside the ClaimsTransformation class.

Comment: @MichaelDoleman - Yet, as suggested, you have not shown that you have attempted to inject an ApplicationUser into your classes constructor.

Comment: Sorry, not clear on that last point: why would I need an ApplicationUser in the constructor, and how would I get it there if it isn't my own code that's instantiating ClaimsTransformation and calling TransformAsync?

Comment: @MichaelDoleman - I thought you said you understood how dependency injection works.  It works by passing the dependency in the constructor.  The framework satisfies the dependencies automatically, you don't create it.